# TWiki & Cygwin configuration

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to configure the cygwin to work with TWiki, I have to input this in the Cygwin bash shell:

mount -b -s c:/...

but it doesn't recognize the "-s", I already fixed the problem with -b, it changed the syntax and now is "mount -o binary" for the "mount -b"part. But now it says unknown option with the "-s" anyone?? help?? or what does the -s mean, so I can look it up :S

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you don't use cygwin. Strawberry perl and native GnuWin32 ports of zip/rcs etc work better.